# Canada visitor visa proof of relationship with inviting friend

Tags: usa, canada, b1-b2-visas, nepal

I am planning to visit Canada for about a week from US. I am in US for about 1.5 months with B1-B2 Visa. I have applied for Canada visa in visit (6 month or less) category.

My friend, who is permanent resident of Canada, has invited me, stating - I am his friend, and provide accommodation, food, travel inside Canada. We used to work together few years ago in our home country. I have already uploaded the invitation letter. But It the submission website requires proof of relationship.

What document can I submit as proof of relationship with my friend?

Edit: Screenshot of the online form that asks for proof of relationship
[image]

When I click the ? mark near it, following information appears

> You must provide proof of your relationship with your host or family member. This can include:
>
> a marriage certificate
>      Statutory Declaration of Common-Law Union (IMM5409)
>      a birth certificate
>      an official document naming you as a parent
>      a copy of the inside back cover of the inviter's passport showing the inviter's parents, if applicable

Comment: When and how did you meet your friend? Do you have evidence of communication between you eg emails, SMS etc?

Comment: We used to work together few years ago. After that he went to Canada. I have updated question also. Please see.

Comment: Are you sure they have asked for mandatory documentary evidence over and above the invitation letter from your friend? http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=421&top=16

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the form asking for proof of relationship.

Comment: My guess would be that you should have chosen a different purpose of travel earlier in the form. This part of the form really doesn't seem to apply to your circumstance. That said, Canada's immigration and visa processes are the most confusing I have ever seen from any country.

Comment: Hello I am in the same situation as you, how did you solve it? Please I need help, I don’t know what kind of document I have to upload and neither my friend living in Canada...

Comment: While entering the information, i checked a option that that indicated I couldn't submit my proof of relationship and the final form didn't ask that information

Comment: Hi How did your application go? did you submit the proof of friendship after all? did you get the visa?

Answer (score 3):

It is strange that the online application system asks your for a proof of relationship, if the person you are visiting is a friend and not a family member nor a spouse. Double check that you have selected the right relationship during the process. In should be this Question 4 on this part of the application:

[image: Canada visa visit to Canada details]

Otherwise, as you mention, there should be an option that you can select stating that you cannot submit a proof of relationship since your host is not directly related to you.

As far as the [Canadian Applying for Visitor Visa User Guide](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/application-forms-guides/guide-5256-applying-visitor-visa-temporary-resident-visa.html#5256E3) goes, a proof of relationship seems to be needed only in case you are visiting family members, spouses, grandchildren, etc. What you need to submit when visiting a friend is [a letter of invitation](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/letter-invitation.html) from said friend. In this letter, the person must specify:

> - complete name,
> - date of birth,
> - address and telephone number,
> - your relationship to the person,
> - the purpose of the trip,
> - how long the person plans to stay in Canada,
> - where the person will stay, and how he or she will pay for things, and
> - when the person plans to leave Canada.

This is where you should explain your relationship with your host.